# Can we force Javascript/jQuery to load fresh (unmodified) version of page from anchor link in modified page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a jQuery function that clones certain elements on a page and then appends them as a list, replacing the prior content.

For background, the items are Wordpress comments of a certain type - posted since datetime "n" - that have been isolated within a *nested* comment structure. The nested comment thread is completely hidden, and a list of the selected comments take their place.

If this seems... peculiar... note that since the comments cannot be shown/hidden as siblings, getting them all meant cloning, re-formatting, and appending them in a list to a page element. The prior nested structure is hidden, and the new list of the selected comments appears in the former space.

So far, so good. Toggling back to the prior version also works fine. Everything works fine except for a last problem: When clicked, links of a certain type (those linking to elements within the same page, identified by id/hash) behave in a less than fully desirable manner.

These *internal* links, when clicked, appear in the browser address bar - .e.g.: `ourhome/page/#itemID`. If the linked item happens to be displayed in the cloned list, they function as normal anchors: We jump to their location within the list. (That's OK, if not necessarily ideal for all possible applications.)

But: *If the element they link to is hidden, nothing happens except that the address in the browser bar changes.*

Ideally, we would automatically force all links when clicked either, if external links, simply to load the linked page as usual, or, if internal, to load a *fresh* version of the page *as displayed in the browser bar* - that is, at the correct linked hash.

Unfortunately for this purpose, **`location.reload()`, `window.history.go(0)` and, assuming I was using them correctly, other simple methods for refreshing the page DO NOT reload with the address in the browser bar, but with the prior address of the page. So the actual internal link is lost.**

Preventing default action on anchor links would seem to serve no purpose here: It merely would prevent the new link from ever making it to the browser in the first place.

**Is there a simple or even a complicated way to force clicked links to load *fresh* versions of the page with the new anchor/hash?**

ADDITIONAL NOTE: This almost works, but doesn't actually go to the anchor on the refreshed page: We see the correct link in the browser bar, but instead go to some other spot on the page, possibly determined by offset(?). (Sub-note: Am using in this example familiar jQuery dollar signs instead of "jQuery" which Wordpress requires for "no-conflict"):

```
    $('a').click(function() {

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    location.assign(url);
    history.go(0);

});
```

Same results so far with `location.reload()`, `window.location.href` and other minor variations...

NEW NEAR-SOLUTION:

```
    $('a').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        window.open(url);

    });
```

In this version we open a fresh new page in another window that at least goes right to the item originally linked - no scroll problems except in a certain complicated secondary case (involving WordPress comment reply links, which present unique handling problems).

Unfortunately, `window.open(url,"_self")` encounters the same problems as with other methods. So, `window.open(url)` still the best solution so far, though still less than ideal.

IN LIEU OF SCREENSHOTS REQUESTED

Function in use and under testing here: http://ordinary-gentlemen.com/developing/2015/08/comments-since-last-visit-reloaded-reloaded-testing-post/

You'll have to leave a comment, or visit and then return later, to access the functions (since they deal with comments left "new since last visit").

I'm leaning toward preferring the "near-solution" over the alternative originally envisioned, but will leave this question unanswered at least for now in case someone has an enlightening answer.

Comment: When you say "If the element they link to is hidden...", do you mean that it's `display: none` or does the element no longer exist on the page?

Comment: it's been toggled to non-display. So, I can add a function to (re-)show it, but that introduces all sorts of complications if done as a reversal of the prior hide function.

Comment: Wait a sec... I think I just solved it... am testing answer...

Comment: nope - see additional note

Comment: Could you add some screenshots?

Comment: I don't believe I can add screenshots here (my reputation scores are too low), but I'll have a working version up probably tomorrow at a site, and I'll include some screenshots in an accompanying post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are wanting a cachebuster.

```
 var url = $(this).attr('href')+'?cb'+Date.now();
```

Also note that you can push pages to the browsers history with javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Interesting, thanks. After I've had a chance to test, I'll see if it answers my original question, and, if it does, check-mark your answer, though, as noted in post updates, for actual intended use I'll probably be going with a variant on the "near-solution."

Comment: Nope - same as before: changes the link that shows in the address bar, but doesn't actually force a fresh reload of the page with `window.open(url,"_self")`. Also, with `window.open(url)`, it opens a new window, but interferes with functioning of the id/anchor - so, even if it could be made to work, doesn't look like an improvement on a `location.reload()`.